# How to know if my Waves node is on fork or not?

Tags: blockchain, wavesplatform

I’m running my Waves node but I can’t figure out if I’m on fork or not. How to know exactly if the node is on a fork or not? is there an utility or API command that show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the blockchain height or the last 100 signatures of blocks to understand if your node is on a fork or not (compare block generators and signatures with other nodes API.
http://dev.pywaves.org/nodes/ can also show the status of nodes).

You can use the [rest api with swagger](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-api-and-sdk/waves-node-rest-api.html) on different nodes to compare block # on both. looking for different generators in the same block height.

Your node can be in one of two possibilities: your node on a fork with height less than 2000 blocks or more than 2000 blocks. In case that your node is on a fork with a height less than 2000 blocks, here you can implement rollback through [rollback instructions](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-full-node/how-to-rollback-a-node.html). Otherwise, you need to choose an option for [Getting Actual Blockchain.](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-full-node/options-for-getting-actual-blockchain.html)